# Data point on regression line: Effect on estimates (simple linear regression)

Tags: maximum-likelihood, linear-regression

I am concerned with the simple linear regression model,

$y_k = a + bx_k + \epsilon_k$,

where $(\epsilon_k)$ are iid normal with mean $0$ and $k=1,...,n$; here $n$ is the number of observations.

I know the usual estimators for $a$ and $b$ from MLE or LS which coincide.

What I am interested in is the effect of a new data point $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ placed on the regression line, that is $y_{n+1}=\hat{a}+\hat{b}x_{n+1}$, where $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$ are the ML-estimates based on the first $n$ observations. Intuitively I would expect new estimates $\tilde{a}$ and $\tilde{b}$ based on $n+1$ observations to equal the old estimates. I have ventured into some tiresome calculations using the known closed formulas for the MLE without success.

Is the conjecture right - and in that case: Is it easily proved?

In addition: I would expect that e.g. $y_{n+1}>\hat{a}+\hat{b}x_{n+1}$ to yield $\tilde{b}>\hat{b}$. Is this true?

Edit: The last statement is of course under the assumption that $x_{n+1}>\max\{x_1,...x_n\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your first expectation is right. In the least-squares formulation, the original regression line has, by definition, the least sum of squared errors for the original data points, and zero error for the new data point, and any other line has non-negative squared error for the new data point; thus the original regression line also has the least sum of squared errors for all of the points.

The additional expectation in the last paragraph is wrong, though. Adding a point above the original regression line will shift the line upwards at that point, but whether that increases or decreases its slope depends on the position of the point. If it's the point with highest $x$ coordinate, it will increase the slope, but if it's the point with lowest $x$ coordinate, it will decrease the slope. (Or perhaps you meant to imply that the points are in order of increasing $x$ coordinates and thus the $(n+1)$-th point added has the highest $x$ coordinate?)

Comment: Exactly - I forgot an additional assumption: $x_{n+1}>\max\{x_1,...,x_n\}$.

Can I ask you to write up your statements mathematically? Your statements are in line with my thinking, but I am not able to translate it to "pure" mathematics.

Comment: @Furrer: Does that apply to the first paragraph, too? I'm aware that the second paragraph doesn't actually contain an argument; I'll try to supply one; but the first paragraph is a full proof in words. I'm not a great fan of putting things in formulas that can be clearly expressed in words.

Comment: It applies to both paragraphs, but I think I can state the argument myself now - after having looked into LS-estimation.

We have that $(\tilde{a},\tilde{b})=\arg \min \sum_{k=1}^{n} \epsilon_k^2 + (y_{n+1}-a-bx_{n+1})^2$. Recall that $(\hat{a},\hat{b})$ minimizes the first term. As the last term is furthermore $0$ when evaluated in those estimates by definition of $y_{n+1}$, the result is established.

Comment: @Furrer: I don't see how that's more "mathematical" than what I wrote, but it's certainly also a valid statement of the argument. I'll think about the second part.

Comment: That is certainly another discussion for another time. Your statement was more than sufficient - after all, it helped me reach my goal. Thank you for considering the second part.

Comment: I think I have an argument. Consider the MLE $\tilde{b} = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(x_k-\bar{x})(y_k-\bar{y})}{\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (x_k-\bar{x})^2}$. The partial derivative wrt. $y_{n+1}$ is by assumption strictly positive! Thus with the previous result established, the desired follows?

Comment: @Furrer: Nice! Then you can generalise that to say that this is the case as long as $x_{n+1}$  is greater than the average of the other $x_i$.

Comment: Yes, that is a fine generalization. Thanks for pointing me in the right direciton.